# Why spinning bullet is more stable in air?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, projectile, aerodynamics, speed

I found out about stagnation point recently, it is an arbitrary edge or point where the stream of air molecules parts. I was wondering could a spinning bullet affects the stagnation point to improve stability in air or it simply just a conservation of momentum on top of being a streamline body? Is it true that anything above mach 5 the stagnation point comes into design considerations, why is that?

Disclaimer: I do not have a hypersonic weapon please don't stomp my door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the [stagnation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_point) as the [pivot contact point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_pressure) of a spinning top with the solid surface (i.e. a table surface for example) upon it is spinning.

[image: gyro-precession]

image credits: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/11-3-precession-of-a-gyroscope/

$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\mathrm{p}}=\frac{m α r}{I_{\mathrm{s}} \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\mathrm{s}}}
$$

where $I_{s}$ is the moment of inertia, $ω_{s}$ is the angular velocity of spin about the spin axis, $m$ is the mass, $α$ is the acceleration of the bullet, $θ$ is the precession angle between the spin axis and the axis of precession and $r$ is the distance between the center of mass and the pivot.

The faster the bullet translates (i.e. higher Mach speed) the closer in distance the stagnation point is located relative to the head tip of the bullet, essentially **shortening the distance $r$** and effectively acting like a shorter pivot axis of a spinning top.

A shorter pivot axis on an object mass which has spin angular momentum will increase its angle of precession $θ$ (i.e. amplitude of precession) therefore decreases the angular velocity $ω_{p}$ of its [gyro-precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) and therefore potentially can in the worst case if the Machs's are too high, destabilize the bullet from its linear straight trajectory and in the best case cause braking of the bullet's speed.

However, expect for relative low linear translational speeds this effect to be minuscule for a spinning bullet and the gain in stability by the spinning action angular momentum to be multi-fold. It just happens the stability gained by spinning reduces a short amount at higher bullet speeds.

[Location of stagnation point on x-axis Calculator](https://www.calculatoratoz.com/en/location-of-stagnation-point-on-x-axis-calculator/Calc-6325?FormulaId=6325)

Comment: Answer was corrected and updated.

Comment: "shortening the distance $r$..." text added to the answer for more clarity.